Waitress server setup in AWS without public IP or other resouces which makes application public
Can anyone please explain how to check if flask/waitress app is working or not in AWS, I am using ollama in the code for the Llama model.
I don't have access to public IP or any other method to connecting the machine publically not avaliable, can anyone please help if somehow it can be resolved.
What I tried:
model is already installed in VM so simple queries with model are working
I wrote one basic flask app and tried to run but it is just loading not showing anything in output
The waitress script which i created is working in local machine but no idea how to get it working in AWS VM.
I want to get it working in AWS but i dont have access to any method which makes the application public.
